# Most reasonably priced way to get from Tokyo Narita to Shinjuku?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, tokyo, nrt

I'm flying into Tokyo Narita at the end of September and will be staying in Shinjuku. As I understand it taxis from the airport are very expensive.

What's the best way to get from the airport to Shinjuku?

Comment: By 'best' then, I assume you mean 'cheapest'? Or relatively cheap?

Comment: You assume correct, perhaps I could have been more clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Narita Express](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/nex/) train runs straight from [Tokyo Narita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narita_Airport_Station) to [Shinjuku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinjuku_Station). Route map:

[image]

Bear in mind that Shinjuku is a huge station and that it's quite easy to get lost or turned around in it. In light of that it may be helpful to figure out which exit you want to take in advance. Here's a map of the exists:

http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/stations/img/map_e/e866.pdf

Also, there's an attached underground mall called Subnade (connected to the Shinjuku station via the East Exit, which takes you to the Metro Promenade, which, in turn, takes you to Subnade) with additional exits:

http://www.subnade.co.jp/english/e-floormap.pdf

For my hotel the optimal exit was # 13 of Subnade. YMMV.

Comment: Can you take the express with a JR pass ?

Comment: Looks like it: http://www.jrpass.com/blogs/jr-pass-on-the-narita-express

Comment: Keep in mind that, at least in principle, reservation is mandatory on the Narita Express. As usual, reservation is free with a JR Pass, but you must still do it.

Comment: If you're not continuing to travel long-distance on the same day, don't use the precious days of your JR-pass for the Narita-Shinjuku journey. You pay much more per day for the JR-pass than you could spend within Tokyo region during the same amount of time.

Answer (score 6):

It's years since I did this but the [airport limousine bus](http://www.limousinebus.co.jp/en/) went straight to the hotel (Shinjuku Washington in my case).  It looks like it still does.

This avoids the need to navigate Shinjuku station just after arriving in Japan, as well as the need to get from the station to the hotel with your luggage -- if the bus stops at your hotel (or the one next door).

Comment: I love the Friendly Airport Limousine Bus!

Comment: For those who have never been in Japan and Korea; keep in mind that it doesn't look like a Limousine, it's still a bus!

Comment: @downhand, indeed, the pictures on their website show that.  Quite comfortable I seem to remember though.

Comment: It can also be agonisingly slow... Took twice as long as the timetable suggested when I took it on a weekday evening (over two hours I think). On the plus side, you don't need to do anything except sit and wait

Answer (score 3):

As usual, [Hyperdia](http://www.hyperdia.com/) will show you all available train connections, just be careful to choose "Narita Airport Terminal 1" (or 2) as your departure station and not just "Narita" (the latter is located in downtown Narita city).

The Narita Express is the only direct rail link between Narita airport and Shinjuku, but it is also the most expensive one. However, since cheaper alternatives require making at least one transfer at a central Tokyo station, I wouldn't recommend it unless you are a fairly seasoned user of Japanese urban rail (and if you were, you wouldn't be asking this question). Nevertheless, for your reference the cheapest train options can be found by unticking the "Limited Express" box in Hyperdia. This will exclude the more expensive *limited express* trains, such as the Narita Express and the Skyliner, from the results and keep only the cheaper, ordinary commuter trains.

As pointed out by Chris H, limousine buses are also an option well worth considering, especially if they stop at or near your hotel.

Answer (score 2):

[Access Narita](http://accessnarita.jp/en/home/) limousine bus is the cheapest option to/from Narita airport. It costs only 1000 yen one-way to Tokyo or Ginza stations and preschool kids are free if sitting in your lap. So, for the family with two preschoolers it costs only 2000 yen one way. From Tokyo or Ginza, it's an additional 200 yen by train to Shinjuku.

Note however that it is only marginally (30 yen) cheaper than an ordinary train on the Keisei Main Line to Nippori. (From Nippori to Shinjuku is also an additional 200 yen.)

Comment: Is this your company?

Comment: @JoErNanO Regardless, I think it's a valid answer, as it is indeed cheaper than all other options I know of. It could be improved, however.

Comment: The OP wanted to go to Shinjuku, which is a train transfer away from either Ginza or Tokyo station. If the answer is edited to include that, it seems reasonable to let it be.

Comment: @fkraiem The rules say they should disclose their affiliation if this is indeed their company. Regardless of whether the answer is valid or not.

Comment: @JoErNanO Out of curiosity, where does it say so? I cannot seem to find it...

Comment: @fkraiem [See this post on our Meta.](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3148/advertising-thats-not-spam/3149#3149)

Comment: @JoErNanO Access Narita is operated by Japan Railways' bus division, so I'm fairly sure it's not "their" company.  I've used their service myself and it's cheap, cheerful and surprisingly fast.

Comment: @jpatokal Excellent that's what we needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

I am going there in April 2016,

Upon researching, I find that Limousine Bus can be pricier option.

**Option 1:** Access Narita bus from Narita -> Tokyo station and then JR train. (1500 yen)
**Option 2:** Keisei Limited Express from Narita -> Tokyo station and then JR train. (1200 yen)
**Option 3:** NEX Train for foreigner -> 2000 yen
**Option 4:** Limousine Bus -> 3100 yen

You can also check this site: http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2027.html

Comment: Thanks, but I've been and gone! Limousine bus was indeed the best price AND easiest way to Shinjuku. It requires almost no work after a 14 hour flight, everything is done for you which is nice. I wouldn't much fancy trying to negotiate Tokyo station, the subway, and then Shinjuku station (which is a nightmare) after a long flight, but good luck to you!